# Ethereum mainnet syncing problem

Tags: blockchain, evm

I am running geth and lighthouse and syncing the ethereum mainnet blocks in fullmode. It has downloaded 190Gbyte block data, but it does not donwload no more data. Geth show following warning message.

`"Becon client online, but no consensus updates received in a whild. Please fix your becon client to follow the chain!"`

In lighthouse, shows following warning.

```
"Low peer count pear count=0 ...."
```

Is there the way I can add manually peers? Or is there any other resolution to resovle the problem?